# Is there a generic approach to automatically make some sysfs controls ch{own,mod} user-accessible?

Tags: permissions, sysfs

My current primary question motivator:

```
$ ls -l /sys/devices/platform/samsung
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 27. jaan  14:17 battery_life_extender
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 19. jaan  18:40 leds
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 26. jaan  23:37 modalias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 27. jaan  12:57 performance_level
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 24. jaan  00:35 power
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    0 19. jaan  18:40 rfkill
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 27. jaan  13:03 subsystem -> ../../../bus/platform
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 27. jaan  13:03 uevent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 26. jaan  23:37 usb_charge
```

I'd like to modify these without sudo. During a desktop session that. Privileged startup script is perfectly OK.

It's feeling like the solution is to have some sort of generic insmod parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be a script, which changes permissions on that files using chmod and then setting you system so it would start the script on system bootup.

Comment: Indeed, simple startup script could do it.

Comment: No sane kernel will honor S[UG]ID bits on scripts (for security reasons), in Perl there used to be a hack around this.

Comment: samsung-laptop.ko entries are solved with a simple `find /sys/devices/platform/samsung -type f -exec chown :wheel {} + -exec chmod g+w {} +` script in /etc/local.d. Unfortunately wifi rfkill state cannot be toggled like this, without elevated privileges, even though respective sysfs entries have been properly modded. I do have 95% of my laptop hotkeys working now as desired, so feels like a win nevertheless.

Comment: As far as i know it is not the kernel who ignores the SUID-Bit, but rather its the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `sysctl(8)`, perhaps through `sudo(1)`? Is it enough to preset them in `sysctl.conf(7)`?

Comment: man sysctl says "for /proc/sys"